# Periodicity with irrational numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, irrational-numbers

Recently, I invented the following theorem and found a proof,
it seems strange since it is very counter-intuitive to me.
The proof is long and non-conceptual.
Is there a place or a branch of math where I can read about it? Or at least a key word?
Any explanation is definitely welcome!
Sorry for my terminology and notation - I am not a mathematician. The corrections to my notation and terminology are definitely welcome.

Suppose we are given a set $S = \mathbb{N}^{+} \cup \mathbb{N}^{+}x$, where $x$ is a positive irrational number. Prove that there exist $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $T\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$, the interval $(\alpha + k T, \alpha + k T + T)$ contains exactly one number from $S$.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that S is supposed to be the set of positive integers together with the multiples of x?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Note that by density reasons, $T$ is necessarily  $x/(x+1)$, and α is necessarily a multiple of $T$. So everything reduces to prove: for an irrational number $0 < T < 1$ and any (large enough)  $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$ the inequalities $Tk< i < T(k+1)$ and $(1-T)k<j<(1-T)(k+1)$ are satisfied either by exactly one $i\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and no $j\in\mathbb{N}^+$ or by exactly one $j\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and no $i\in\mathbb{N}^+$. Which  is easy to verify. Your theorem is nice anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is what I've got for $T$ and $\alpha$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Pietro Majer explained in a comment, the result (which is nice) reduces to the statement that for an irrational number $0<T<1$, any $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$ is of the form $\lfloor\frac{n}{T}\rfloor$ or $\lfloor\frac{n}{1-T}\rfloor$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, but not both. This is known as Rayleigh's theorem or Beatty's theorem, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence).